# Referencing structure member using array of strings?

Tags: c, struct

I have some autogenerated c code from Matlab/Simulink containing a structure of parameter values where the members are the parameter names them selves. Something like this

```
Param.ParameterName1 = 5;
Param.ParameterName2 = 10;
```

Then I have a array of strings (`ParameterList`) which contains the parameter names. What i would like to do is to use the parameter names from `ParameterList` to reference a member of the structure, so i can assign new values to the parameters. Something like this:

```
i = 1;
Param.ParameterList[i] = 10;
```

Is this even possible? Is there another way to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: So the structure looks like `struct { int ParameterName1; int ParameterName2; /* and you want to add code here*/ } Param;`. And you want to add some members to the structure to reference existing members?

Comment: Hi Kamil. I would like to reference existing parameters and change their values. But the structure looks like you mentioned.

Comment: A standard-compliant (strictly conforming) solution could be constructed using a table (array) containing the values of `offsetof` for the various structure members along with some helper functions or macros to take an index, look up the offset, add it to the structure base address (as a `char *`), and convert the resulting pointer to a pointer to the member type. It would be ugly and inefficient. Do you really need it?

Comment: Thanks for the hint about offsetof Eric. Did not know that one. In a helicopter view what i need is a way to set the value of a select set of members of the structure. The selection of members i need to change the value of is listed in a array of strings. I don't really have control of how the target structure is made since this is auto generated code from Simulink.

Comment: Another approach would just be to write two big ugly functions (possibly auto-generated) to copy all the the members one-by-one to or from an array, and then do all your work on the array.